# What is the correct format for Apache Cordova ios package name

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm using Cordova CLI on MAC. I'm trying to build but I recieve the following error:

```
Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found:
No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the bundle identifier “com.hamooz.JasmineGarden” were found.
```

My team identifier is: 4MNA9C87LH and App ID Name is: JasmineGarden
I think the problem is the bundle name, what should I rename my bundle to?

Answer (score 0):

According to your log, you should name your bundle `com.hamooz.JasmineGarden`